# Овощи «борщевого» или «борщового набора»

Tags: грамотная-речь, или

В СМИ везде с буквой Е. А тут пишут на грамоте, что с О... Это перевернуло мой мир! Как же правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Орфографический словарь фиксирует оба варианта.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]